# cambiar el maximo y el minimo en un slideriput shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, slider, shiny

Quiero construir un gráfico dinámico que adapte el maximo y el minimo en el sliderinput de acuerdo a la columna que se seleccione  para trabajar, ya que cada columna es un indice diferente y tiene escala diferente, se que me falta un reactive pero no sé como construirlo. Tengo esto:

```
    ui
    tabItem("IndicesI",
    tabsetPanel(position= "left",
        tabPanel("Indices de ingreso", icon = icon("file-medical-alt"),
        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("SeleccioneIndice"),
                    uiOutput("Rango"),
                    uiOutput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2"),
                    checkboxInput("Todas","Seleccione Todas/Ninguna", value = FALSE),
                    uiOutput("RandeDatedI")
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("lineplotI"),
                    dataTableOutput("summary7")
```

hasta aquí todo bien, sigue el server

```
     output$SeleccioneEspecialidad2<-renderUI({
     selectInput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2", "Seleccione Especialidad",
            BDnuevo$specialty.name, multiple = T, selected = TRUE )
        })
      BD9<-reactive({
      BDnuevo %>%
      filter(specialty.name %in% input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2 )
      }) 
      output$SeleccioneIndice <-renderUI({
      selectInput("SeleccioneIndice", "Seleccione Indice", choices= 
        c("Ments"="escalas.ments","Fragilidad"="escalas.fragilidad","ElixhauserAHRQ"="escalas.elixhauserAHRQ","ElixhauserVanWalraven"="escalas.elixhauserVanWalraven"
       ))
       })
```

En este punto es donde creo me falta el reactive para que conforme se escoge la columna en el output seleccione indice, se ajuste el rango

```
       output$Rango<-renderUI({  
       sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = 0, 
          max = 5, value =c(1,2))
       })
       FechaI<-reactive({
       BD9.1<-BD9()
       unique(BD9.1$simpleOriginDate)
       })
       output$RandeDatedI <-renderUI({
        dateRangeInput('dateRangeI',
               label = 'Seleccione un rango',
               start = min(FechaI(),na.rm=T), max(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
          )
          })
         BD9.2<-reactive({
         BD9.3<-BD9()
         BD9.3 %>%
         filter(simpleOriginDate >= input$dateRangeI[1] & simpleOriginDate <= 
          input$dateRangeI[2]) %>%
          group_by_at(as.factor(input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2)) %>%
        summarise(across(input$SeleccioneIndice,list(min,median,max,IQR),na.rm=T),
        n=n())->tmpI 
         names(tmpI)<- c("Nombre","Minimo","Mediana","Maximo","RQ","n")

         tmpI

         })
          output$summary7<-DT::renderDataTable({
         datatable(BD9.2(), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
        order = list(list(3, 'desc'))))
      })
     })
```

Mi intension es contruir una tabla y con la información y luego graficar